# How to prevent show mat-menu on click?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to show and hide Mat-menu on mouseover and mouseout,but how to prevent show mat-menu on click?

HTML

```
<button mat-mini-fab color="primary" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"
  (mouseenter)="openMenu()">
  <img class="face" *ngIf="isLoginIn()" [src]="faceUrl">
</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <div (mouseleave)="closeMenu()">
    <button class="login-menu-item" mat-flat-button color="primary">Login</button>
    <button class="login-menu-item" mat-flat-button color="">Logout</button>
  </div>
</mat-menu>
```

Comment: Can you please reproduce it in angular-material stackblitz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a div instead of a button, then you would just need to get a template reference to the `matMenuTrigger` to call the open and close methods on your `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

```
<div mat-mini-fab color="primary" #menuTrigger="matMenuTrigger [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" (mouseenter)="menuTrigger.openMenu()">
  <img class="face" *ngIf="isLoginIn()" [src]="faceUrl">
</div>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <div (mouseleave)="menuTrigger.closeMenu()">
    <button class="login-menu-item" mat-flat-button color="primary">Login</button>
    <button class="login-menu-item" mat-flat-button color="">Logout</button>
  </div>
</mat-menu>
```

**Revision**

Looks like creating a wrapper `DIV` for the `mat-menu` and assigning the `matMenuTrigger` to that wrapper `DIV` will prevent opening the menu via click on the top `MENU DIV`.

```
<div (mouseenter)="menuTrigger.openMenu()">Menu</div>
<div #menuTrigger="matMenuTrigger" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" >
       <div (mouseleave)="menuTrigger.closeMenu()">
          <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
          <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
       </div>
    </mat-menu>
</div>
```

Comment: a div can still be clicked

Comment: You are correct, I thought a div would avoid that but doesn't seem to. I am looking into this, if not able to find a way to stop it, I will delete this answer.

Comment: Please see revision to this answer for possible workaround.

Comment: Thank you！I give a 'z-index' to the top div,it is working good.

Comment: No problem, please be sure to accept as answer. Also know that there is a feature request currently being debated to add open matMenu on hover... Depending on the outcome there may be an official feature for this in the future.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I have the same set up as the revision but added a `(click)="doSomething()"` function. When I click the `div`, it still opens the menu and does not call my function. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I did also not want a mat-menu to open on mouse click. I want to solely control it programatically.

I've solved it by applying the css-rule `pointer-events: 'none'` which tells the HtmlElement to not emit click events if the user interacts with it. As the `matMenuTriggerFor` directive [listens for click events](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/822e3e0c2b97f87de21a34f3e486805d302d932b/src/material/menu/menu-trigger.ts#L79), it will not open.

```
<div [ngStyle]="{cursor: 'pointer'}">
  <div [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" [ngStyle]="{'pointer-events': 'none'}">
    <!-- Your Content -->
  </div>
</div>

<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Foo<button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Bar<button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Baz<button>
</mat-menu>
```